# Pyspark - read data from elasticsearch cluster on EMR

Tags: amazon-web-services, apache-spark, authentication, elasticsearch, pyspark

I am trying to read data from elasticsearch from pyspark. I was using the elasticsearch-hadoop api in Spark. The es cluster sits on aws emr, which requires credential to sign in. My script is as below:

```
from pyspark import SparkContext, SparkConf sc.stop() 
conf = SparkConf().setAppName("ESTest") sc = SparkContext(conf=conf) 
es_read_conf = { "es.host" : "vhost", "es.nodes" : "node", "es.port" : "443",
"es.query": '{ "query": { "match_all": {} } }',
"es.input.json": "true", "es.net.https.auth.user": "aws_access_key", 
"es.net.https.auth.pass": "aws_secret_key", "es.net.ssl": "true", 
"es.resource" : "index/type", "es.nodes.wan.only": "true" 
}

es_rdd = sc.newAPIHadoopRDD( inputFormatClass="org.elasticsearch.hadoop.mr.EsInputFormat", 
keyClass="org.apache.hadoop.io.NullWritable", 
valueClass="org.elasticsearch.hadoop.mr.LinkedMapWritable", conf=es_read_conf)
```

Pyspark keeps throwing error:

> py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling
>   z:org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD.newAPIHadoopRDD.
>
> : org.elasticsearch.hadoop.rest.EsHadoopInvalidRequest: [HEAD] on
>   [index] failed; servernode:443] returned [403|Forbidden:]

I checked everything which all made sense except for the user and pass entries, would aws access key and secret key work here? We don't want to use the console user and password here for security purpose. Is there a different way to do the same thing?